# Java String ReplaceAll method giving illegal repetition error?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a string and when I try to run the `replaceAll` method, I am getting this strange error:

```
String str = "something { } , op";
str = str.replaceAll("o", "\n"); // it works fine
str = str.replaceAll("{", "\n"); // does not work
```

and i get a strange error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
Illegal repetition {
```

How can I replace the occurrences of `"{"` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A `{` is a regex meta-character used for range repetitions as `{min,max}`. To match a literal `{` you need to escape it by preceding it with a `\\`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\{", "\n"); // does work
```

Answer (score 20):

If you really intend to replace single characters and not regexes (which is what you seem to want to do here), you should use `.replace()`, not `.replaceAll()`. In spite of its name, `.replace()` will replace ALL occurrences, not just the first one.

And in case you wonder, `String` implements `CharSequence`, so `.replace("{", "\n")` will work.

Comment: Holy crap... I've been using Groovy for years and always assumed `replace()` just replaced the first instance. That's what I get for not looking at the docs!

Answer (score 6):

Escape it:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\{", "\n");
```

This is needed since the first argument to [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and `{` has a special meaning in Java regular expressions (it's a *repetition* operator, hence the error message).