# Java split and replace a string with value

Tags: java, string, split

I have a following string which I have to split and replace the value on some condition

```
http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}
```

in which I have to replace the value only for  {uploadType}/{uploadName} . I really don't know how to go about to replace them with value.

The strings which are in `{uploadType}/{uploadName}` can be of any type to replace.

I've tried something like the following :

package com.test.poc;

```
public class TestString {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String toBeFixed = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}"; 
    String[] toReplaceWith =toBeFixed.split("{");
for (String string : toReplaceWith) {
    System.out.println("string : "+string);
}   
}

}
```

but i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:2775)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1889)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1752)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1460)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1133)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:823)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2292)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2334)
    at com.test.poc.TestString.main(TestString.java:9)
```

EDIT :

this is the method i tried based on `Sean Patrick Floyd` answer

```
public String doPOSTPathVariable(String uri,List paramsList) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, Exception{
        String uriString="";
        UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri).build();
        for (int j = 0; j<= paramsList.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println("path variable");
            MethodParams methodParams;
            methodParams =(MethodParams) paramsList.get(j);

            if(methodParams.isPrimitive() && methodParams.getDataType()=="boolean"){
                  uriString = uriComponents.expand(true).encode().toUriString();
            }
            if(methodParams.isPrimitive() && methodParams.getDataType()=="java.math.BigDecimal"){
                uriString = uriComponents.expand(123).encode().toUriString();
            }
            if(methodParams.isPrimitive() && methodParams.getDataType()=="java.lang.String"){
                uriString = uriComponents.expand("hexgen").encode().toUriString();
            }
       } 
        return uriString;
    }
```

but i get following exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'uploadName'
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.access$1(UriComponents.java:431)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$FullPathComponent.expand(UriComponents.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandInternal(UriComponents.java:413)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:404)
    at com.hexgen.tools.HexgenClassUtils.doPOSTPathVariable(HexgenClassUtils.java:208)
    at com.hexgen.reflection.HttpClientRequests.handleHTTPRequest(HttpClientRequests.java:77)
    at com.hexgen.reflection.HexgenWebAPITest.main(HexgenWebAPITest.java:115)
```

Could some one help me on this please?

Comment: the no of parameter to be replaced will be deducted at the run time only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `{` is a regex `meta-character` used for range repetitions.

before doing that

```
toBeFixed = toBeFixed.replaceAll("\\{", "\n");
```

see docs also :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Similar question :[Java String ReplaceAll method giving illegal repetition error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491116/java-string-replaceall-method-giving-illegal-repetition-error)

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/
uploadType}/
uploadName}` is the out put if i follow your code, how can i replace those two with value

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [`UriBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html)?

```
UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}").build("foo", "bar");
```

(Conveniently happens to use the exact formatting you are using)

Comment: the no of parameter to be replaced will be deducted at the run time only

Comment: With `UriBuilder` being a builder pattern, you can iteratively add components to it using its convenience methods that return itself. Its exists for your situation exactly like yours, much cleaner than regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring MVC, this functionality is available out of the box [with the new URI builder technology](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-construct-encode-uri).

```
UriComponents uriComponents =
    UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(
        "http://example.com/hotels/{hotel}/bookings/{booking}").build();

URI uri = uriComponents.expand("42", "21").encode().toUri();
// or:
String uriString = uriComponents.expand("42", "21").encode().toUriString();
```

(In fact you can still use this technology, even if you don't use Spring MVC, but you'll need to have the Spring MVC jar on the Classpath, obviously)

Comment: I have followed your input but it gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'uploadName'` will update the question now

Comment: @Anto this method only works if you know the number of parameters at compile time

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one :

```
public class TestString {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
String toBeFixed = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}"; 
String[] toReplaceWith =toBeFixed.split("\\{");
for (String string : toReplaceWith) {
System.out.println("string : "+string);
}   
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

UrlBuilder is the solution, but if you are just looking around delimiters, you can also use substrings:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}";
int lastSlash = url.lastIndexOf('/');
int secondLastSlash = url.substring(0, lastSlash).lastIndexOf('/');
System.out.println(url.substring(secondLastSlash+1, lastSlash));
System.out.println(url.substring(lastSlash+1));
```

To remove the curly braces, you can use String.replace('{', '') and String.replace('}', '') on the strings