# How to replace a particular string with value in java

Tags: java, string

EDIT :

Goal : `http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/test/test`

```
Is it possible to have some thing like `{a-b, A-B..0-9}` kind of pattern and match them and replace with value.
```

i have following string

```
http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}
```

there can be any no of strings like `{uploadType}/{uploadName}`.

how to replace them with some values in java?

Comment: Make a separate string with name `uploadName' and concatenate it to your parent string

Comment: it is not static string and it is dynamic string, that is where i am struggling and blinking where to start

Comment: You already asked this question, why are you asking again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335539/java-split-and-replace-a-string-with-value/16335575#16335575

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamic? Do you mean there will not be a fixed number of components to replace?

Comment: Thanks only now this question is understood clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited] Apparently you don't know what substitutions you'll be looking for, or don't have a reasonable finite Map of them. In this case:

```
Pattern SUBST_Patt = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\w+)\\}");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( template);
Matcher m = SUBST_Patt.matcher( sb);
int index = 0;
while (m.find( index)) {
    String subst = m.group( 1);
    index = m.start();
    //
    String replacement = "replacement";       // .. lookup Subst -> Replacement here
    sb.replace( index, m.end(), replacement);
    index = index + replacement.length();
}
```

Look, I'm really expecting a +1 now.

---

[Simpler approach] `String.replace()` is a 'simple replace' & easy to use for your purposes;  if you want regexes you can use `String.replaceAll()`.

For multiple dynamic replacements:

```
public String substituteStr (String template, Map<String,String> substs) {
    String result = template;
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> subst : substs.entrySet()) {
        String pattern = "{"+subst.getKey()+"}";
        result = result.replace( pattern, subst.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

That's the quick & easy approach, to start with.

Comment: i am sorry to ask what will be in this `Map<String,String>`

Comment: @Anto Maps all have unique keys and values attached to it. So since the key is the first, that is the one you want to replace, and the other is the value you want to replace it by. For example :Map<keyToReplace,valueOftheReplacer>

Comment: if i know what key to replace that there is no need for me to ask this question here Lyrion. I am sorry

Comment: Thanks @Anto. I've actually used similar technique in commercial software.. it's been popular with clients.

Comment: Hi Thomas this is also the expected answer, thanks for that. Thomas could your give me your email id please.

Comment: Hi Thomas not able to get you on java room, just wanted to ask few things, would you be able to spend few mins with me?. Sorry for late reply, away for lunch

Comment: @Anto  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29351/room-for-thomas-w-and-anto -- I'm interested in contracting, but busy working & don't really give general advice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29353/discussion-between-thomas-w-and-anto)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace method in the following way:

```
    String s = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}";
    String typevalue = "typeValue";
    String nameValue = "nameValue";
    s = s.replace("{uploadType}",value).replace("{uploadName}",nameValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the string that start from {uploadType} till the end.
Then you can split that string using "split" into string array.
Were the first cell(0) is the type and 1 is the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}";
String result = s.replace("uploadType", "UploadedType").replace("uploadName","UploadedName");
```

EDIT: Try this:

```
String r = s.substring(0 , s.indexOf("{")) + "replacement";
```

Comment: `{uploadType}/{uploadName}` this can be anystring but the common is `{}` that is why i am blinking

Comment: That is not a static string, it is a dynamic string. see my comment and edit as well, thanks for the post

Comment: @Anto See my answer using indexOf().

Comment: this will replace everything and will remain wit one value like `http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/replacement` for given example string

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

```
String uploadName = "xyz";
String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/" + uploadName;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
String uploadName  = "xyz";
String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadName}";
url.replace("{uploadName}",uploadName );
```

**Solution 3:**

```
String uploadName  = "xyz";
String url = String.format("http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/ %s ", uploadName);
```

Answer (score -1):

The [`UriBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) does exactly what you need:

```
UriBuilder.fromPath("http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/{uploadType}/{uploadName}").build("foo", "bar");
```

Results in:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/upload/form/foo/bar
```

Comment: i have already commented that it is not static string and dynamic:(

Comment: If you mean to say that there will not be a fixed number of parameters to add, that is not an issue. If it is dynamic then you will be iteratively replacing the components anyway, look at the `UriBuilder` methods in the link and see how you can put the URI together dynamically before assuming this solution is only applicable to static strings and downvoting - there's a reason this got 3 upvotes when you asked this very question just minutes ago.