# how to replace angel bracket string

Tags: java, string, replaceall

I need to replace all kinds of string that look like `{\'\i}` by just `i`

I've already read [Java String ReplaceAll method giving illegal repetition error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491116/java-string-replaceall-method-giving-illegal-repetition-error)

So I tried

```
String word = "something{\\\'\\\i}".replaceAll("\\\\{\\\'\\\i}", "DONE");
```

but it doesn't work, could anyone help me please?

Comment: Why are you trying to replace a different string than the one you've defined in your original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll` expects regular expressions. Instead of trying to get the RegEx right, use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
String word = "something{\\'\\i}".replace("{\\'\\i}", "DONE");
```

Comment: ok, you are right, thank you , but if i need to replace them all? it's just a part of the text... so i need to ask if it still contains and "replace" again until it doesnt cotain?

Comment: `replace` does replace all occurrences of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

```
String word = "yourtexthere"
String newWord = word.replaceAll("{\'\i}", "i");
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean ^^. Use word.replaceAll(%WHATYOUWANTTOREPLCE%, %WHATITSHOULDBE%). If you want all "{" replaced use: word.replaceAll("{", "i") for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final String a = "text{\\'\\i}";
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(a.replace("{\\'\\i}", "i"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use the replace function instead of replaceAll as the last one expects a regex as argument, Ex:

```
String word = "something{\\'\\i}".replace("{\\'\\i}", "'i' /* or i */");
```

`\` has to be escaped in java, thats why we have `\\`

Answer (score 0):

Since `replaceAll` uses a regex, you need to escape all the relevant characters (`{}\`), like this

```
"something{\\'\\i}".replaceAll("\\{\\\\'\\\\i\\}", "i");
```

The `\\\\` is because you're escaping the `\` first in a Java String, then in the regular expression to match a literal `\`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    word = "{\'\i}";
    a = word.replace("{"," "");
    a = a.replace("}", "");
    a = a.replace("'", "");

</script>
```

Just create another rule with the character you want to replace. 
Not a very good solution but its the most "clean".

Comment: This would replace all sorts of other things, say `{1}`, any other instance of `'`, etc. etc. It's not the most "clean" by any stretch of the imagination, it's just bound to go wrong sooner or later.

Comment: this will only replace any characters that he wants. Just create a rule for each one...if the initial string is {1} the output will be 1 and that is what is wanted. Or at least i thought so

Comment: But he doesn't want to remove all of those characters with no other restrictions, he wants to remove those characters if they're around the `i`. Your code will have loads of side effects under certain conditions; consider for example the (arbitrarily chosen) String `"{x} 'hello' {\'\i}"` - your solution results in `"x hello \\i"`, the desired result is `"{x} 'hello' i"`. Note that your solution doesn't even remove the backslashes.